# python script to convert " into a html tag

Tags: python

I would like to add two html tags to this file. Each line ends with `<br>` which is done via something like

```
>>> f = open("/tmp/x","r")
>>> con = f.readlines()
>>> for line in con:
...   print line + "<br>"
...
```

Now I would like to replace `"` with specific html tag `<h3>`. For ex, I have file with content

```
       This is test file named "file.txt" and below is the way to 
       understand its data and values etc
       This is line "one" is also "tricky" to change
```

expected output is :

```
       This is test file named <h3>file.txt</h3> and below is the way to <br>
       understand its data and values etc<br>
       This is line <h3>one</h3> is also <h3>tricky</h3> to change <br>
```

I'm thinking about have two flags for appearance of " . If its odd then use <h3> else use </h3>  something like that.If you anyother solution , please suggest.

Comment: Your output is not valid HTML by any recent standard.  Is that okay with you?

Comment: Yes,that's fine with this requirement.

Comment: If you used `<br/>` it would be _closer_ to compliance. (And wrapping it with `<div>`, closer still.)

Comment: thanks Malvolio, will ensure these tags are properly used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `import re` at the top of your code,

```
line = re.sub(r'"([^"]*)"', r'<h3>\1</h3>', line)
```

should do the substitutions you show in your examples.

This doesn't catch an "extra/odd/spare" occurrence of `"`, only **pairs** of `"`s -- if you need to do some other substitution to the "odd" double-quote if any, that's easily arranged as a next step of processing for `line`.

Comment: You might want to use `+` instead of `*` -- so that empty quotes don't become empty an `h3` and disappear.

Comment: Cool nice thanks, It worked perfectly! . Okay sure, I understand this may not produce perfect output for any kind of inputs. I'll do a review of these output manually before using them. Thanks!

Comment: @Malvolio, maybe, but this really depends on the OP's clarifying their specs -- in the Q as now shown I don't see any exception for "nothing between the doublequotes pair" (or "only space" or other cases one might perhaps want to single out for special treatment).

Comment: @lakshmipathi, always glad to help -- be sure to remember to come back later when you can accept and do so:-)